# Solving $\sin(x) = \ln(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

While tutoring a student in introductory calculus, I inquired as to how she would set up an integral to determine the volume of the solid created by revolving the region bounded by the functions $\sin(x)$, $\ln(x)$, and the $x$-axis about the line $y=5$. She set up the integral as follows: $$\pi\int_{1}^{a} 25-(\ln(x))^2 dx + \pi\int_{a}^{\pi} 25-\sin^2(x)dx $$ where $a$ is the solution to $\sin(x) = \ln(x)$. However, I couldn't give an explanation as to how to find this point. Is this something that could be solved given two years of introductory calculus, or does it require a larger toolkit? In searching for an answer to this problem online, I was bombarded by hits on $\ln(x)$ differentiation resources which obviously weren't helpful. Any light you could shed would be appreciated!

Comment: It might just so happen that it will disappear in the final calculations. Maybe it does this time

Comment: It's a numerical matter,  it's not likely that there's any sort of closed form solution.  Newton's method should be fine, or even a simple binary search.  [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+sin(x)%3Dln(x)) tells us the answer is about $2.21911$.

Comment: $\displaystyle x \in \left[{1 \over \mathrm{e}},\mathrm{e}\right]$.

Answer (score 4):

Numerical methods are the way to go. Clearly there would be only one solution which can be figured by considering the monotonicity of $\ln x$ and the boundedness of $\sin x$. It would help if you're allowed to use a calculator.

Define $f(x)=\sin x-\ln x$. By Newton Raphson method we have the following iterative formula.
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\dfrac{\sin x_n-\ln x_n}{\cos x_n-1/x_n}$$

I'm going to make a first guess say $x_0=2$. Now use the iteration formula to obtain an accurate value of the solution: $$\begin{array}{|p{3cm}||p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|}\hline n & x_n  \\ \hline 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 2.23593406389 \\ 2& 2.21918552153 \\ 3& 2.21910715064\\\hline \end{array}$$

Comment: No,  You can't be a class 10 student (from your profile) , I am sure about that...

Comment: Well I am @Darkrai

Comment: What!!!! Which school/University?

Comment: I'm in Cambridge School in Punjab. Why do you ask?

Comment: And where are you pursuing your Complex Analysis course? I am asking because most of the schools don't offer a "Complex Analysis" course to a class 10 student in India...

Comment: That's from Coursera, online MOOC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91393/discussion-between-paras-khosla-and-darkrai).

Comment: I may misunderstand what you're saying [and this is only a minor quibble], but monotonicity of $f$ and boundedness of $g$ doesn't guarantee only one solution. For example, the function defined by $f(x) = \frac{1}{100}x$ is strictly monotone and intersects many times with $g(x) = \sin x$.

Comment: @Eff $\log x$ goes on increasing $\forall x$ but $\sin x$ is stirctly confined to $[-1, 1]$ so actually confirming graphically by using concavity and increasing/decreasing statistics tells us that. but yes it does not generally hold for reasons you pointed out. Cheers :))

Comment: @ParasKhosla Right, you can make a more detailed argument, and you'd be correct. Just wanted to make sure what you were saying. (By the way, I upvoted your answer. It's good)

Comment: @Eff Thanks for providing insights and correcting my thoughts on the problem. Cheers :))

Comment: @ParasKhosla But if you are allowed a calculator, wouldn't it be easier just to plot the functions. Newton's method is good, but only when a problem explicitly asks

Comment: @Dude156 I meant the sort you're allowed in a test situation one that can do the following operations $\pm, \times, /, \sin x, \cos x, \ln x$ and the more basic stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If the student is allowed a graphing calculator, then you can set plot y=sin(x) and y=ln(x) on the graph and use the calculator to find the intersection (I'm a high-schooler and I did this to find intersections in Calc 2)